# Can someone review my implementation of a Queue?

Tags: java, queue

So here is my Queue interface:

```
public interface Queue<E> {
    /**
     * Add an item to the rear of the queue.
     *
     * @param item
     *            Item to be added.
     */
    public void enqueue(E item);

    /**
     * Remove and return the item at the front of the queue.
     *
     * @return The item that was removed.
     */
    public E dequeue();

    /**
     * @return The item at the front of the queue.
     */
    public E frontValue();

    /**
     * @return How many elements are in the queue.
     */
    public int length();

    /**
     * Remove all the items in the queue.
     */
    public void clear();
}
```

And here is my actual implementation:

```
public class LinkedQueue<E> implements Queue<E> {
    private SinglyLinkedListNode<E> front;
    private SinglyLinkedListNode<E> rear;
    private int size;

    /**
     * Create a new LinkedQueue object.
     */
    public LinkedQueue() {
    this.init();
    }

    private void init() {
    // only one object is constructed
    this.front = this.rear = new SinglyLinkedListNode<E>(null, null);
    this.size = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void enqueue(E value) {
    this.rear.setNextNode(new SinglyLinkedListNode<E>(value, null));
    this.rear = this.rear.getNextNode();
    this.size++;
    }

    @Override
    public E dequeue() {
    if (this.size == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("In method dequeue of class "
            + "LinkedQueue the linked queue is empty can cannot"
            + " be dequeued");
    }

    E item = this.front.getNextNode().getValue();
    this.front.setNextNode(this.front.getNextNode().getNextNode());

    if (this.front.getNextNode() == null) {
        this.rear = this.front;
    }
    this.size--;
    return item;
    }

    @Override
    public E frontValue() {
    if (this.size == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("In method frontValue of class "
            + "LinkedQueue the linked queue is empty");
    }
    return this.front.getNextNode().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
    return this.size;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
    this.init();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a easy to read String representation of the linked queue's
     * contents.
     *
     * Example: < 1 2 3 4 5 6 >
     */
    public String toString() {
    StringBuilder linkedQueueAsString = new StringBuilder();
    linkedQueueAsString.append("< ");
    System.out.println("front.getNextNode: " + this.front.getNextNode());
    for (SinglyLinkedListNode<E> node = this.front.getNextNode(); node != null; node = node.getNextNode()) {
        linkedQueueAsString.append(node.getValue());
        System.out.println(node.getValue() + ",");
        linkedQueueAsString.append(" ");
    }
    linkedQueueAsString.append(">");
    return linkedQueueAsString.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** name your interface `Queue`, since `java.util.Queue` already exits.

Also it would be helpful if you post the source of `SingleLinkedListNode`.

The source looks fine to me, you could however add two methods like (append/en-queue, remove/de-queue):

`SingleLinkedListNode<E> append(SingleLinkedListNode<E> newNode)` that will replace

```
 this.rear.setNextNode(new SingleLinkedListNode<E>(value, null));
 this.rear = this.rear.getNextNode();
```

and returns the next node.